# JavaScript tables flicker on load/refresh. Would like to know how can I avoid this happening?

Tags: javascript

I have had some success integrating this code snippet with my data tables.

The only problem is that there seems to be a flicker of all the tables on screen when the page is loading or refreshing, before even entering any search/filter/query words.

I have tried using hide/show with CSS and variations of displaying results in JavaScript and HTML, but with no ultimate fix. I would love to know how to resolve this problem and with keeping mark.js highlight in effect.

```js
var input, table, rows, markInstance;

window.onload = function init() {
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);

  clear();
}

function ContactsearchFX() {

  clear();

  if (input.value.length == 0) return;

  filterRows(input.value);
  highlightMatches(input.value);
}

function clear() {
  markInstance.unmark();

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function filterRows(text) {
  var part = text.toUpperCase();
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

    if (td) {

      var content = td.innerText.toUpperCase();

      if (content.includes(part)) {
        row.style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}

function highlightMatches(text) {
  markInstance.mark(text);
}
```

```css
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.hints {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

myInput:invalid~.hints {
  display: block;
}

mark {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.js"></script>

<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
        Search Titles: 
        <input id="myInput" type="text" required 
               onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" 
                   placeholder="Search Titles" />
    
            <span class="hints">
          Hints: type "git", "bit", "forge" ...
        </span>
      </label>
</div>

<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td> * DATA
      <TABLES> NESTED IN HERE *
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Ps have had no problems with mark.js

Answer (score 3):

There are a few implicit actions being taken by the browser which is causing the flickering.

As the DOM is modified, it causes the browser to reflow (it must calculate the positioning of each element on the page and then redraw all of them).

Normally, modifying the DOM will not cause the page to flicker when small modifications are made once which do not alter the structure of the page, especially since a one time change (while noticeable) does not necessarily constitute "flickering".

However, modifying the DOM in a loop, where each iteration causes a reflow, will cause flickering assuming that the dimensions of relative elements are changing.

This brings us the table aspect. Tables inherently balance out their internal dimensions by definition. They run an algorithm to determine what the sizing of each element should be. This happens during the reflow.

Thus, at each iteration, when the DOM is modified with a table element or an internal table element has its content modified, not only does the entire page redraw, but it potentially redraws with a slightly different set of element sizes depending on the contents of the table. This causes the flickering.

The simply way to fix this would be to construct the set of tables that are going to be placed in the DOM in an element which is in memory only, and then append that element once after the construction is complete. While this will cause a visual change to the page, it will only occur the one time and will not produce the flickering you are encountering.

Comment: I understand most of this Travis, thankyou very much. I wounder could you possibly give me an example?

Comment: @Outtheresomewhere - It is hard to give an example without the table structure you are using, or the approach being used to modify the tables or construct them. I edited the example in your post to a snippet, perhaps you could recreate the issue there and then I or someone else will be able to demonstrate how to remove the flickering with a usable solution.

Comment: Hi Travis thanks but I'm stuck, this site unfortunately cant fit the amount of data I use in my tables. Any alternative ideas?

Comment: It doesn't need to be all the data, or even exact data, just a small amount to at least depict the structure and show a little bit of how it looks.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code I would suggest a few tweaks in your code which may help in performance enhancements and will probably fix your issue with flicker.

`clear()` function is called before performing any filtering which sets all the rows to `display: none` and then in the next loop when any row matches it will set to `dipslay: ‘’`.

I would rather suggest to avoid two loops and perform this operation in a single loop in such a way that whichever row matches your criteria, let it be available for display and whichever is not matching your search criteria, simply set the display none to them.

So avoid setting all of them to `display: none` first and only set those rows as `display: none` which doesn’t match your criteria.

Comment: Would be great if I could have an altered example snippet?